# Use values stored in a string as Enum Object?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have an enum. And a string contains the name of the enum. I want to access the enum using the string. Something like this. But this does not work :(

```
public enum Level {     HIGH,     MEDIUM,     LOW }
def x = "Level"
println "$x".values();
```

Comment: Can u pls add some valid java code you have tried so far.

Comment: May be something like this in java : public enum Level {     HIGH,     MEDIUM,     LOW }
String x = "Level";
System.out.println(x.values());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Class.forName` method. For example

```
    public enum Level {     
        HIGH,     
        MEDIUM,     
        LOW 
    }

    def clazz = Class.forName("Level")
    println clazz.values()
```

Remember you should use FULLY QUALIFIED CLASSNAME. For more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```groovy
public enum Level {     HIGH,     MEDIUM,     LOW }
def x = this.class.classLoader.loadClass('Level', true)
println x.values()
```

Here's an alternative way:

```groovy
public enum Level {     HIGH,     MEDIUM,     LOW }
def x = "Level"
println Eval.me("${x}").values()
```

Comment: The question is how to achive this with a string.

Comment: This won't work. Actually i have a random input string, and i know that string contains name of the enum. I want to get the values of the enum from the input string.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're after now.

Comment: @AsishPati please see my updated answer. It will now do what you wanted it to.

Comment: The alternative displays "No such method" exception. But the first way is working. Thanks

Comment: Well it worked on my machine, but maybe I've got a different implementation of groovy than you. What version are you using? I'm using groovy-2.4.1.